# Access/Mount read-only WebDAV (Hetzner Storage Box)

Tags: linux, mount, webdav

I have a Hetzner Storage Box. One of the features it offers is `sub-accounts' that have their own username (u000000-sub1) and password with the root being a sub-directory of the main account. The main account is read/write by default. However sub-accounts can be set to read-only.

With read-only enabled I'm unable to mount the sub-account via the WebDAV protocol using `davfs2` (or Windows).

```
> sudo mount -t davfs -o ro https://u000000-sub1.your-storagebox.de /mnt/z
Please enter the username to authenticate with server
https://u000000-sub1.your-storagebox.de or hit enter for none.
  Username: u000000-sub1
Please enter the password to authenticate user u000000-sub1 with server
https://u000000-sub1.your-storagebox.de or hit enter for none.
  Password:
/sbin/mount.davfs: mounting failed; the server does not support WebDAV
```

**Note**: Disabling read-only on the service and mounting it using the above command is successful. I'd however prefer to mount the share with read-only enabled on the service rather than via the `davfs` command.

Mounting the main account (which is `rw`) works fine:

```
> sudo mount -t davfs https://u000000.your-storagebox.de /mnt/z
Please enter the username to authenticate with server
https://u000000.your-storagebox.de or hit enter for none.
  Username: u000000
Please enter the password to authenticate user u000000 with server
https://u000000.your-storagebox.de or hit enter for none.
  Password:
> ls -alh /mnt/z
total 512
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 104 Jun 28 12:06 .
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root   0 Jun 28 12:06 TEST
drwx------ 2 root root   0 Jun 28 13:05 lost+found
```

Hetzner advised that I 'Google' to find a client that supports accessing their sub-accounts via WebDAV when read-only is enabled... I did and couldn't find anything that worked.

I'm admittedly not familiar with WebDAV. Can anyone offer any insight as to if/how it'd be possible to access this `sub-account` with read-only enabled via any WebDAV client on any OS?

Answer (score 1):

Hetzner confirmed that `davfs` and Windows client can't access a sub-account with **read-only** enabled via WebDAV.